# How can I mock the following statement by using PowerMockito?

Tags: java, junit, powermockito

I have a class written like so:

```
public class AccountInformationManager {
    private ControlSubAccountInfoDAO contSubAcctDao = (ControlSubAccountInfoDAO) (AppContext.getSpringContext().getBean("controlSubAcctDAO"));

     .....

}
```

AppContext.getSprintContext() returns an object of type ApplicationContext

What I've tried so far:

```
    @RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
    public class AccountInformationManagerTest {

      @Mock
      ControlSubAccountInfoDAO controlSubAccountInfoDAO;
    
      @Before
        public void setup() throws Exception {
            PowerMockito.when(AppContext.getSpringContext().getBean(anyString())).thenReturn(controlSubAccountInfoDAO);
            accountInformationManager = new AccountInformationManager();
        }
    
    
    }
```

But I am gettinga null pointer exception in the line:

```
PowerMockito.when(AppContext.getSpringContext().getBean(anyString())).thenReturn(controlSubAccountInfoDAO);
```

Comment: You don't. **The entire point** of dependency injection is that you don't call `getBean`, you provide a constructor of `AccountInformationManager(Dao dao)` and let Spring handle looking things up.

Comment: But given this state of the code, how can I mock the statement?. I can't modify the codebase.

Comment: I am running this test from the test module. At that time, I don't think the beans are initialized from the main module.

Answer (score 1):

I think you may write something like:

```
PowerMockito.when(AppContext.getSpringContext()).thenReturn(aContext/* an object implementing SpringContext interface, which method getBean() returns mocked controlSubAccountInfoDAO */);
```